# How to multiply all elements of one list with first element of second list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, multiplication

I have two lists; list1 and list2. list1 consists of 5 elements and list2 consists 18 elements and each element of list2 in turn consist of a (41X41) 2D array. How can I multiply the first element of list1 with all the 18 element of list2? I have to do this multiplication for all the five elements of list1.

I tried

```
List<List<Double>> Q = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();   
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    List<Double[][]> list=new ArrayList<>(list2.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
        Double P[][] = new Double[41][41];
        for (int k = 0; k < 41; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < 41; l++){
                P[k][l] = list1.get(i) * list2.get(j)[k][l];
                }
            }
            list.add(P);
        }
        Q.add(list);
     }
```

Is there a better way to do it to make it less complicated to understand?

Comment: How do you define the multiplication operation between a number and a matrix of numbers? The way they define it in linear algebra?

Comment: Thanks..I understand that but please read the other comments to understand what I am talking about..

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my comment, and your other comments are not helpful. When you have to multiply all elements by all elements, it first means you have to multiply one element by one element, right? But an "element" in one list is a number. An "element" in the other list is an array. Normally you can only multiply a number by a number, so we needed to know what you mean when you say you want to multiply a number by an array.

Comment: A number can be multiplied by a matix, simply multiplication of the number by all the element of the matrix. I needed to multiply each element of list1 to all the elements of list2. Hope I am making myself clear. This is how I am doing it now  for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){ List<Double[][]> list=new ArrayList<>(list2.size()); for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){Double P[][] = new Double[10][10]; for (int k = 0; k < 41; k++){for (int l = 0; l < 41; l++){P[k][l] = list1.get(i) * list2.get(j)[k][l];}}list.add(P);}}  I wanted to avoid too many for loops, it makes code look complicated.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you have information to add to your question, [edit] it and add the information there, properly formatted. If you want to perform matrix multiplication by a scalar, you'll need loops. If the code looks too complicated, it means you should separate the matrix multiplication into its own method.

Answer (score 2):

If each of the elements of list2 consist of a matrix, you should tell Java you want to access the element in the first row and first column.

```
double y = list1.get(0)*list2.get(0)[0][0];
```

Comment: That would mean applying a loop..That would make it four loops then as eventually I have to multiply all the elements of list1 with all elements of list2.
 for (int i = 0; i<list1.size(); i++{

Comment: This is how I was doing it for(int i =0; i <list1.size; I++){ for (j=0;j<5;j++){double y = list1.get(0)* list2.get (0)}}  According to you there would be two more for loops for accessing the elements of 2D arrays in list2..?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you need to multiply number with array. But the result of such an operation must be array too.

```
 double[][] resultArray = new double[10][10];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; i < 10; j++) {
         resultArray[i][j] = list1.get(0) * list2.get(0)[i][j];
     }
 }
```

If you want to multiply two arrays I mean list1 with every element of list2 then it's impossible because you can't multiply 1x2 array with 10x10 array. To achieve this the number of elements in the first array must be 10, i.e the number of elements (columns) in the first array must match the number of rows in the second array.

Comment: Yes, I have to ultimately multiply all the elements of list1 to all elements of list2 but not at once..means I have to multiply one element of list1 to all elements of list2 at one time and then the second element of list1 to all elements of list2..